# Output PHP Mysql Date format to ISO 8601 with "T" sign only

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get a datetime formatted a specific way. Can I do this in MySQL or do I need to do it in PHP?

This is the output from MYSQL :

```
2016-01-30 23:21:46
```

I need it formatted in this (similar but not exactly the same) fashion:

```
2016-01-30T23:21:46
```

Is there a PHP function to handle this correctly or is it possible to change it from MYSQL?

Comment: You could do a basic `str_replace` for the first space to a `T` or you could use `strtotime` on the MySQL format then use `date` to reformat based on the timestamp from `strtotime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `insert()`:

```
select insert(<whatever>, 11, 1, 'T')
```